# Google Play Services Consumes more RAM in my APP

Tags: memory-management, xamarin.android, google-play-services

My app uses foreground service when running. When I inspect the memory usage in running services it is taking higher than usual. Basically my app consumes around 100MB but additionally, 150MB is consumed by these 2 google play services.
com.google.android.gms.persistent - 100MB
com.google.android.gms - 50MB
So In total, it makes around 350MB. How can I stop these play services?

Comment: Is this helpful to you ？

Answer (score 1):

Google Play Services is basically a package that provides updated api support for apps regardless of what Android version you are running.

It is a very well known fact that android suffers from fragmentation. Mainly due to lack of updates from OEMs.

Hence Google play services comes into play. It ensures that you get a better experience even if you are on an older flavour of Android.

Most Google apps + Games with Play Games support + Majority Sync enabled apps need play services to work.

The only way out of this is to uninstall updates to google play services and disable google play services.

You will notice that your phone will start to perform better since google play services is a very processor heavy app. Disabling it will increase your battery life, free up storage and make the phone smooth.

In case you haven't guessed the cons, here they are.

You lose support for all google apps. All latest versions of Google apps need the updated version of Play services installed.

You will have to hunt for alternative apps.

Microsoft has almost all apps on the play store competing with google’s own offerings. Search the play store.

**If** you still want to disable the google service,you could follow below:

go to your phone’s **Settings** > **Applications** > **All and open Google Play Services**. You will get to know about the app’s detail and a few other options here. Just tap on the “**Disable**” button. It will generate another pop-up message. Confirm it by tapping on the “**Ok**” button. This will disable Google Play Services on your device. Later, you can follow the same drill to enable it as well.

Comment: @RaviKiran I'm afraid the code does not allow to force a stop  of Google's service by design and by contract

Answer (score 1):

cited text "Settings > Applications > All and open Google Play Services. You will get to know about the app’s detail and a few other options here. Just tap on the “Disable” button" WILL NOT DISABLE AT ALL. As if some other app using google play services start, then google play services package will start as well.

The only way is to safe uninstall google play, via ADB command line:
adb uninstall -k --user 0 com.google.android.gms
also I reccommend to delete google play:
adb uninstall -k --user 0 com.android.vending

Disabling via ADB also has no effect at all (other apps will re-enable  google)
adb shell pm disable-user --user 0  com.agui.screenshot

if some day you need to download other app, search for its apk, just search app_name apk download, and if no success, reinstall again on Android phone, install app and remove google again, google is part of the plandemic and part of the globalism

cmd package install-existing --user 0 com.android.vending
cmd package install-existing --user 0 com.google.android.gms